# What's the regular way of assertion in C?

Tags: objective-c, assert

I'm using NSAssert macro for Objective-C assertion, and it's the regular way to do this.
But it's not work in C functions. What do I should use for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSCAssert()` (and also `NSCAssert1()`, ... up to `NSCAssert5()` )

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <assert.h>

...

assert(<expression>);
```

([reference](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.1.html))

Answer (score 4):

```
void assert(int expression); 

If expression evaluates to 0 (false), then the expression, source code filename, 
and line number are sent to the standard error, and then calls the abort 
function. 

If the identifier NDEBUG ("no debug") is defined with #define NDEBUG then the 
macro assert does nothing.
```

Example:

```
assert(x != 0);
```

*note*: Include [`assert.h`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.1.html)

Comment: Also note http://vgable.com/blog/2008/12/04/nsassert-considered-harmful for `assert(x != 0 && "what the hey?")`... cool stuff.